# Error while entering provider in module ts

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

While I am trying to `import` `nativepagetransition` in providers, it shows an error.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { LinkPage } from '../pages/link/link';
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
LinkPage,


],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
LinkPage

],
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
 NativePageTransitions,


 {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
 ]
 })
 export class AppModule {}
```

The error is,

```
Type ‘NativePageTransitionsOriginal’ is not assignable to type ‘Provider’.
Type ‘NativePageTransitionsOriginal’ is missing the following properties from type ‘FactoryProvider’: provide, useFactory [2322]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the **native modules and services** in **ionic 4+** have been move to ***ngx directory*** of the module.
Like

**In ionic 3**:

```
We were importing NativePageTransitions from @ionic-native/native-page-transitions
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';
```

**Now in ionic 4+:**

```
We have to import native modules from @ionic-native/module-name/ngx directory.
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx';
```

Answer (score 2):

The error comes if you installed the wrong native plugin version for your project type.

Check the project type in ionic.config.json

If the type is "ionic-angular", then install 4.x.x version.

example

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/native-page-transitions@4.20.0
```

If the type is "angular", then install 5.x.x-beta version

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/native-page-transitions@5.0.0-beta.24
```

**Note:**

Add ngx at the end of import only if you are using **Angular 6**

```
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx';
```

if not remove ngx from the import both in app.module.ts and app.component.ts

```
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';
```

**Refencence**:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15225#issuecomment-414074074

Answer (score 0):

You installed the latest `@ionic-native/native-page-transitions` (v5+).

Then you should import `NativePageTransitions` from `@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx`

```
import { NativePageTransitions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions/ngx';
```